# Temporary relational databases

Tags: java, derby

For some reason, when I make a Derby database from Java, it works for a while, but then I cannot access the tables (as if they have been deleted). Most of what I have been doing to those tables is querying them. Other than that, I add data to them. I have tried remedying this by calling `statement.executeUpdate("autocommit off");` and then `statement.executeUpdate("rollback");` Has anyone else encountered these same issues? If so, did you find any causes?

Comment: I found the correct way to turn the autocommit off and then rollback; it all needs to be done via the Connection Object http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html //namely, write something like
`connection.setAutoCommit(false); connection.rollback(someOptionalSavePoint);`

Comment: I don't understand the question. Are you asking about how to turn off autocommit? Or are you asking why your tables seem to be unexpectedly empty?

Comment: Read the first sentence. The tables, for some reason, seem to delete themselves, as I am able to access them and add data to them, until some point where something happens to the table that causes it to not be accessible anymore.

Comment: Why are you trying to turn off autocommit and rollback the changes to the database?  If your databases are being cleared it would seem like you wouldn't want to do that. That's why @BryanPendleton was confused.  I am as well.

Comment: I am trying to roll it back to when said table was a valid table. I assumed that, until the user deletes the data, it is persisted.

Comment: To be more specific, I got the `"Table/View 'nameOfValidTable' does not exist"` error when querying nameOfValidTable, although I have queried (and added to!) nameOfValidTable numerous times in the past!